# Writing a sed command

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm supposed to write a regular expression using `sed` such that every line whose first non-blank character is either a `+` or a `-` must be terminated by a space and `\\`.
For instance a line that looks like:

```
    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
```

must turn into:

```
    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
```

I tried to do:

```
/^[       ]- s/$/ \\\\/g
```

but it's not working.
How can I do this?

Comment: Most obviously, you're missing a closing slash on your regex.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat testfile 
-u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
 u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
+u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
```

Consider this `sed` command:

```
$ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*[-+]/ s/$/ \\\\/' testfile
-u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
 u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
+u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
```

`/^[[:blank:]]*[-+]/` selects lines whose first non-blank or tab character is `-` or `+`.  For those lines, a substitute command adds `\\` to the end of the line.

Or, if you only want one `\` in the output:

```
$ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*[-+]/ s/$/ \\/' testfile
-u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \
 u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
+u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \
```

Note that `[:blank:]` is a unicode-safe character class that matches blanks and tabs.

Comment: Note that `[ \t]` is meant to match on space, backslash or `t`, though the GNU implementation of `sed` only does it when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point.   I updated the answer to use the POSIX character class `[:blank:]` in place of the GNU form `[ \t]`.

Comment: This would add ` \\ ` to lines that already had ` \\ ` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
     u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
    +u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\

    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
     u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
    +u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name

$ sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*[+-]/s/( \\\\)?$/ \\\\/' file
    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
     u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name
    +u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\

    -u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
     u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
    +u, -\hspace{.01cm}-unset name \\
```

The above `sed` command locates lines that starts with a `+` or `-`, preceded by optional spaces or tabs.  Once such a line has been found, it removes any `\\` preceded by a space  at the end of the line (if present) and then appends a space and `\\` at the end of the line.

This way, we don't add `\\` to the end of lines that already has that string there.